# How to prove if function is strictly monotonic increasing

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

I have this function and I have to prove that this function is strictly monotonic increasing

This is the equation: $$a_n = \frac{3n-7}{8+5n}$$

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: you may  try to use the fact that a sequence $a_n$ is increasing iff the sequence $b_n = (5/3)a_n -1 $is increasing.

Comment: Not a good idea to ask for "the best way...", "easiest way..."  Those matters are in the eye of the beholder.  Besides, if you get someone willing to offer a way, you should be grateful to know one way, since you clearly haven't shown any attempt at any proof whatsoever.

Comment: What is the function? I'm not going to chase links to find it. It's easy enough for you to type it into your question, if the question matters to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: induction. $a_1>a_0$, in fact $-\frac 7 8<-\frac 4 {13}$. Than given that $a_n>a_{n-1}$ let's show that $a_{n+1}>a_n$. You have $a_{n+1}=\frac {3(n+1)-7} {8+5(n+1)}=\frac {3n-4} {13+5n}, a_n={\frac {3n-7} {8+5n}}$, so you have to show that $\frac {3n-4} {13+5n}>\frac {3n-7} {8+5n} \iff(3n-4)(5n+8)>(3n-7)(13+5n)\iff 15n^2+4n-32>15n^2+4n-91$

and it's done.

Comment: Could you please add more details.

Comment: @Michael Beggars can't be choosers.  Please ask specific questions. Have you tried to prove by induction?

Comment: @Michael: the question of the hour is "Could **you** provide more details, in **your** post?  If you ask a question with no details, no effort, no explanation, you have no right to insist that others give you any more than they graciously gave you, given the little you provide.

Comment: Did you mean $a_1>a_0$?

Comment: You're right, I was too vague.

Answer (score 1):

Write $a_n$ as: $$a_n=\frac{15 n - 35}{15 n + 24} = 1 - \frac{59}{15n + 24}$$

then notice that:

- $15n+24\;$ is strictly positive and **in**creasing, thus
- $\frac{59}{15n + 24}\;$ is **de**creasing, thus
- $-\frac{59}{15n + 24}\;$ is **in**creasing, thus
- $a_n=-\frac{59}{15n + 24} + 1\;$ is **in**creasing.

---

[ EDIT ]    The above makes use of the known (and otherwise easy to prove) properties:

- if $f(x) \gt 0$ for all $x$, then $f(x)$ is [strictly] **in**creasing $\iff$ $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is [strictly] **de**creasing;
- $f(x)$ is [strictly] **in**creasing $\iff$ $-f(x)$ is [strictly] **de**creasing.